# Did Hemingway write about intentional contagion during World War I?

Tags: identification-request, ernest-hemingway

I have this vague recollection about Hemingway writing, in one of his novel, about intentional contagion of infection; it seems to me there is a character, near a trench, offering a cigarette pack containing some infected substance to another character.

Did Hemingway write about intentional contagion during World War I?

I did some web search and it is not "Throng at Smallpox Case".